# Capostrano: cap aborted! Don't know how to build task 'start' (See the list of available tasks with `cap --tasks`)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, puma, rbenv, capistrano3

there is a lot of issues found in the web with this problem, but I don't found one to resolve my issue and it is difficult understand all.

This is my single problematic.

I began rewrite an **ruby on rails** app using **rbenv**. I want try to deploy this app with **Capistrano** **Puma** and **Nginx** (does I need also Passenger or can I only use Puma ?)

I have write my project on a local machine. and now I am trying  deploy it in a server. but from the beginning I have this issue with Capistrano config.

Here what's wrong ?

```
$ cap --tasks --trace
** Invoke load:defaults (first_time)
** Execute load:defaults
cap aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'start' (See the list of available tasks with `cap --tasks`)
/home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/task_manager.rb:59:in `[]'
/home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/task.rb:405:in `[]'
/home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/capistrano-3.14.1/lib/capistrano/dsl/task_enhancements.rb:7:in `before'
/home/deploy/ecran-village-plannings/config/deploy.rb:85:in `block in <top (required)>'
/home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/task_manager.rb:232:in `in_namespace'
/home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/dsl_definition.rb:141:in `namespace'
/home/deploy/ecran-village-plannings/config/deploy.rb:76:in `<top (required)>'
/home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:29:in `load'
/home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:29:in `load_rakefile'
/home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/default_loader.rb:11:in `load'
/home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:781:in `load_imports'
/home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/capistrano-3.14.1/lib/capistrano/application.rb:105:in `load_imports'
/home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:711:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:104:in `block in load_rakefile'
/home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:103:in `load_rakefile'
/home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:82:in `block in run'
/home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:80:in `run'
/home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/capistrano-3.14.1/lib/capistrano/application.rb:14:in `run'
/home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/capistrano-3.14.1/bin/cap:3:in `<top (required)>'
/home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/bin/cap:23:in `load'
/home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/bin/cap:23:in `<main>'
```

Here are my files:

**Gemfile**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.7.2'

gem 'rails-i18n'
# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 6.0.3', '>= 6.0.3.3'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3', '~> 1.4'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 4.1'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '>= 6'
# Transpile app-like JavaScript. Read more: https://github.com/rails/webpacker
gem 'webpacker', '~> 4.0'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.7'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
# Use Active Model has_secure_password
gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'
gem 'sorcery'
# Use Active Storage variant
# gem 'image_processing', '~> 1.2'

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.4.2', require: false
# gem "dotenv-rails"

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development, :production do
  #Add Capistrano
  gem 'capistrano'
  gem 'capistrano-rails'
  gem 'capistrano-bundler'
  gem 'capistrano-rbenv' 
  gem 'capistrano3-puma', github: "seuros/capistrano-puma"
  gem 'capistrano-nginx'
  gem 'capistrano-ext'
  
  # Access an interactive console on exception pages or by calling 'console' anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '~> 3.2'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

group :test do
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '>= 2.15'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  # Easy installation and use of web drivers to run system tests with browsers
  gem 'webdrivers'
end
```

**Capfile**

```
require 'capistrano/setup'
require 'capistrano/deploy'
require 'capistrano/bundler'
require 'capistrano/rails/assets'
require "capistrano/rails/migrations"
require 'capistrano/rbenv'
require 'capistrano/nginx'
require 'capistrano/puma'
install_plugin Capistrano::Puma
install_plugin Capistrano::Puma::Nginx
# Load the SCM plugin appropriate to your project:
#
# require "capistrano/scm/hg"
# install_plugin Capistrano::SCM::Hg
# or
# require "capistrano/scm/svn"
# install_plugin Capistrano::SCM::Svn
# or
# require "capistrano/scm/git"
# install_plugin Capistrano::SCM::Git

# Include tasks from other gems included in your Gemfile
Dir.glob("lib/capistrano/tasks/*.rake").each { |r| import r }

#set :rbenv_type, :user
#set :rbenv_ruby, '2.7.2'
```

**config/deploy.rb**

```
# config valid for current version and patch releases of Capistrano
lock "~> 3.14.1"

server 'seances.ecranvillage.ovh', roles: [:web, :app, :db], primary: true

set :repo_url, "git@framagit.org:rodinux/ecran-village-plannings.git"
set :application, "ecran_village_plannings"
ask :branch, 'master'
set :bundle_without, %w{development test}.join(' ')

set user: 'deploy', roles: %w{app db web}
# Default value for :format is :airbrussh.
# set :format, :airbrussh

# You can configure the Airbrussh format using :format_options.
# These are the defaults.
# set :format_options, command_output: true, log_file: "log/capistrano.log", color: :auto, truncate: :auto

# Default value for :pty is false
set :pty, true
# Default value for :linked_files is []
append :linked_files, "config/master.key", "config/database.yml"

# Default value for linked_dirs is []
append :linked_dirs, "bin", "log", "tmp/pids", "tmp/cache", "tmp/sockets", "vendor/bundle" "public/system", "storage"

# Default value for default_env is {}
#set :default_env, { path: "/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH" }
#set :linked_files, fetch(:linked_files, []).push('config/database.yml', 'config/secrets.yml')

# Default value for linked_dirs is []
#set :linked_dirs, fetch(:linked_dirs, []).push('log', 'tmp/pids', 'tmp/cache', 'tmp/sockets', 'vendor/bundle', 'public/system', 'public/uploads' )

# Rbenv specific settings
set :rbenv_path, '/home/deploy/.rbenv/'
set :rbenv_type, :system # or :system, depends on your rbenv setup
set :rbenv_ruby, 'ruby 2.7.2p137'
set :rbenv_prefix, "RBENV_ROOT=#{fetch(:rbenv_path)} RBENV_VERSION=#{fetch(:rbenv_ruby)} #{fetch(:rbenv_path)}/bin/rbenv exec"

# Default value for local_user is ENV['USER']
# set :local_user, -> { `git config user.name`.chomp }

set :rails_env, 'production'
# Default value for keep_releases is 5
set :keep_releases, 5
# if you want to remove the dump file after loading
set :db_local_clean, true
# if you want to remove the dump file from the server after downloading
set :db_remote_clean, true
# if you are highly paranoid and want to prevent any push operation to the server
set :disallow_pushing, false

# Uncomment the following to require manually verifying the host key before first deploy.
# set :ssh_options, verify_host_key: :secure
set :puma_threads,    [4, 16]
set :puma_workers,    2
set :use_sudo,        false
set :stage,           :production
set :deploy_via,      :remote_cache
set :deploy_to,       "/home/#{fetch(:user)}/apps/#{fetch(:application)}"
set :puma_bind,       "unix://#{shared_path}/tmp/sockets/#{fetch(:application)}-puma.sock"
set :puma_state,      "#{shared_path}/tmp/pids/puma.state"
set :puma_pid,        "#{shared_path}/tmp/pids/puma.pid"
set :puma_access_log, "#{release_path}/log/puma.error.log"
set :puma_error_log,  "#{release_path}/log/puma.access.log"
set :ssh_options,     { forward_agent: true, user: fetch(:user), keys: %w(~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub) }

set :nginx_config_name, 'ecran_village_plannings'
set :nginx_server_name, 'seances.ecranvillage.ovh'

set :puma_preload_app, true
set :puma_worker_timeout, nil
set :puma_init_active_record, true  # Change to false when not using ActiveRecord
set :puma_workers, 2

namespace :puma do
  desc 'Create Directories for Puma Pids and Socket'
  task :make_dirs do
    on roles(:app) do
      execute "mkdir #{shared_path}/tmp/sockets -p"
      execute "mkdir #{shared_path}/tmp/pids -p"
    end
  end

  before :start, :make_dirs
end

namespace :deploy do
  desc "Make sure local git is in sync with remote."
  task :check_revision do
    on roles(:app) do
      unless `git rev-parse HEAD` == `git rev-parse origin/master`
        puts "WARNING: HEAD is not the same as origin/master"
        puts "Run `git push` to sync changes."
        exit
      end
    end
  end

  desc 'Initial Deploy'
  task :initial do
    on roles(:app) do
      before 'deploy:restart', 'puma:start'
      invoke 'deploy'
    end
  end

  desc 'Restart application'
  task :restart do
    on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 5 do
      invoke 'puma:restart'
    end
  end

  before :starting,     :check_revision
  after  :finishing,    :compile_assets
  after  :finishing,    :cleanup
  after  :finishing,    :restart
end
# when using db, you should add config/database.yml here
# set :linked_files, fetch(:linked_files, []).concat(%w{.rbenv-vars})
# set :linked_dirs, fetch(:linked_dirs, []).concat(%w{log tmp/pids tmp/cache tmp/sockets vendor/bundle})
```

**/config/deploy/production.rb**

```
# server-based syntax
# ======================
# Defines a single server with a list of roles and multiple properties.
# You can define all roles on a single server, or split them:
set :stage, :production # this defines production stage for deployment

set :branch, 'master'
server "seances.ecranvillage.ovh", user: "deploy", roles: %w{app db web}, my_property: :my_value
# server "example.com", user: "deploy", roles: %w{app web}, other_property: :other_value
# server "db.example.com", user: "deploy", roles: %w{db}




# role-based syntax
# ==================

# Defines a role with one or multiple servers. The primary server in each
# group is considered to be the first unless any hosts have the primary
# property set. Specify the username and a domain or IP for the server.
# Don't use `:all`, it's a meta role.

# role :app, %w{deploy@example.com}, my_property: :my_value
# role :web, %w{user1@primary.com user2@additional.com}, other_property: :other_value
# role :db,  %w{deploy@example.com}



# Configuration
# =============
# You can set any configuration variable like in config/deploy.rb
# These variables are then only loaded and set in this stage.
# For available Capistrano configuration variables see the documentation page.
# http://capistranorb.com/documentation/getting-started/configuration/
# Feel free to add new variables to customise your setup.



# Custom SSH Options
# ==================
# You may pass any option but keep in mind that net/ssh understands a
# limited set of options, consult the Net::SSH documentation.
# http://net-ssh.github.io/net-ssh/classes/Net/SSH.html#method-c-start
#
# Global options
# --------------
set :ssh_options, {
    keys: %w(/home/deploy/.ssh/id_rsa),
#    forward_agent: false,
#    auth_methods: %w(password)
}
#
# The server-based syntax can be used to override options:
# ------------------------------------
# server "example.com",
#   user: "user_name",
#   roles: %w{web app},
#   ssh_options: {
#     user: "user_name", # overrides user setting above
#     keys: %w(/home/user_name/.ssh/id_rsa),
#     forward_agent: false,
#     auth_methods: %w(publickey password)
#     # password: "please use keys"
#   }
```

I have add files like /config/secrets.yml, etc...

I perhaps don't use the good practise to use Capistrano... why can't I have to do ?

Comment: does `bundle exec cap --tasks --trace` work?

Comment: `bundle exec` solved the issue for me.

Comment: Have you figured this out? I just upgraded my Rails app to 6.1 and am now having the exact same issue

Answer (score 1):

its mainly due to the ruby,rails and ubuntu updated version issues. I got the same problem.

Added in Capfile this line before the last line and that solved my issue(only if your puma version is < 5 ).

```
install_plugin Capistrano::Puma::Daemon
```

For reference follow the below tutorial. Would be helpful for someone. Because I spent lot of time to find a solution for this.
https://matthewhoelter.com/2020/11/10/deploying-ruby-on-rails-for-ubuntu-2004.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this to your Capfile as per the docs

`install_plugin Capistrano::Puma::Daemon  # If you using puma daemonized (not supported in Puma 5+)`

Cheers

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I am going back to use my old app without capistrano, if I could...

Answer (score 0):

`bundle exec cap --tasks --trace` works

```
cap puma:make_dirs                  # Create Directories for Puma Pids and Socket
cap puma:nginx_config               # Setup nginx configuration
cap puma:phased-restart             # phased-restart puma
cap puma:restart                    # restart puma
cap puma:start                      # Start puma
cap puma:status                     # status puma
cap puma:stop                       # stop puma
cap puma:workers:count              # Add a worker
cap puma:workers:less               # Worker--
cap puma:workers:more               # Worker++
```

but `cap <environment> deploy` fails

```
➜ cap coffee deploy:check --trace
** Invoke coffee (first_time)
** Execute coffee
** Invoke load:defaults (first_time)
** Execute load:defaults
cap aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'start' (See the list of available tasks with `cap --tasks`)
/Users/ram/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/task_manager.rb:59:in `[]'
/Users/ram/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:405:in `[]'
/Users/ram/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/capistrano-3.14.1/lib/capistrano/dsl/task_enhancements.rb:7:in `before'
config/deploy.rb:207:in `block in <top (required)>'
/Users/ram/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/task_manager.rb:232:in `in_namespace'
/Users/ram/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/dsl_definition.rb:141:in `namespace'
config/deploy.rb:199:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/ram/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/capistrano-3.14.1/lib/capistrano/setup.rb:27:in `load'
/Users/ram/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/capistrano-3.14.1/lib/capistrano/setup.rb:27:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/ram/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/capistrano-3.14.1/lib/capistrano/configuration/variables.rb:32:in `untrusted!'
/Users/ram/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/2.7.0/delegate.rb:83:in `method_missing'
/Users/ram/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/capistrano-3.14.1/lib/capistrano/setup.rb:26:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/ram/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:281:in `block in execute'
/Users/ram/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:281:in `each'
/Users/ram/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:281:in `execute'
/Users/ram/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:219:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/ram/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:199:in `synchronize'
/Users/ram/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:199:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/ram/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/task.rb:188:in `invoke'
/Users/ram/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `invoke_task'
/Users/ram/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/Users/ram/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `each'
/Users/ram/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `block in top_level'
/Users/ram/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:125:in `run_with_threads'
/Users/ram/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:110:in `top_level'
/Users/ram/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:83:in `block in run'
/Users/ram/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/ram/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:80:in `run'
/Users/ram/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/capistrano-3.14.1/lib/capistrano/application.rb:14:in `run'
/Users/ram/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/capistrano-3.14.1/bin/cap:3:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/ram/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/bin/cap:23:in `load'
/Users/ram/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/bin/cap:23:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => coffee
```

Fixed: add `bundle exec` to `cap <environment> deploy` command

What changed?: I was using `oh-my-zsh` with `bundler` plugin that auto-load `bundle exec` in my shell, but lately I removed it to speed up terminal startup

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Sorry, I have try delete rbenv to install rvm and now I have other issues... I go back to the first project which was deploy from five years and released, but without capistrano and puma, as before pulsed with passenger. But the bad idea was to try changing my version manager...